# Adding yum to a red hat docker container using tar only

Tags: docker, installation, containers, redhat, yum

I have a **minimized** Docker container image, based on **red Hat 7**.

It has no tools such as yum, rpm, wget, etc.

I need to **install yum** using **tar only**. (having a package ready and just extract it).

Is it possible?

Comment: you need at least rpm to go ahead.

Comment: Is there a way to install rpm from a tar?

Comment: I don't seem to recall any option as such.